# Problems with the HQL Query

Tags: hibernate, hql

Below is my HQL Query.

```
delete from Table t 
where 
    (t.column1=:value1 and t.column2=:value2) 
    or (t.column3=:value3 and t.column4=:value4)
```

When I run this query it generates the following SQL which is wrong.

```
delete from Table t 
where 
    t.column1=? 
    and t.column2=?
    or t.column3=? 
    and t.column4=?
```

The parentheses are removed in the generated SQL which is giving me the wrong result.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats not a structured solution, but just to make things work. Can u plz try this

```
 delete from Table t 
    where 
        1=1 AND (t.column1=:value1 and t.column2=:value2) 
        or (t.column3=:value3 and t.column4=:value4)
```

i dnt have hibernate installed at the momenet, but i believe once this issue came to me and i resolved it like this (I guess so)

[NHibernate HQL logic problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287300/nhibernate-hql-logic-problem)

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-550

after going through these links, i have figured out (this may be wrong) that Hibernate is translating these queries perfectly.
"AND" has a higher precedence, so results of query should not be effected at all...there might be some other reason

Comment: @Ashish going through above links might help

Comment: @Ashish I tested the queries in sql, qith parenthesis and without parenthesis, it gives same result. explanation in above links is perfect.